# An other permalink problem - 404 Error

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I know there are already a lots of post about this question, but not a single one helped me to solve this issue.

I moved my page to an other server and afterwards I was facing the problem that the permalinks stopped working. I use the following permalink: `/%postname%/`

The `.htaccess` file is set properly see the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I set the permlinks back to standard it seems to work. mod_rewrite is loaded, but I'm not sure if `AllowOverride` is set to "All", how can I check this without having access to the `httpd.conf` file. I'm on a shared host.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: How did you move your site? What were the steps? I would ask your host about `mod_rewrite` and `AllowOverride`, just to be sure.

Comment: Transfer all files to the new server, export and import the MySQL database, adjust wp-config.php. The site is running sofar check: http://www.lrk-bw.de/

Comment: Looks like you got this resolved. Can you answer your question or remove it?

Comment: Your hint was perfect. I asked my host about mod_rewrite and AllowOverride and he was able to solve the problem. Thanks ;)